# Extremely slow boot, with kernel error

Tags: boot, dual-boot, kernel, dmesg, timeout

I am new at the forum, sorry for the orthography.
I have Ubuntu Budgie 18.04 because my previous OS was getting freezed after login, however this Ubuntu is ridicously slow since I select between linux and Windows 10, yes I have dual boot, but there is the mistery, windows 10 takes 2 minutes to get ready,and this ubuntu takes 4 minutes and 27 seconds to get ready for using, well 26 seconds because I need one second to write the password, so I have been searching in the internet, but to be honest I am new in this world of gnu/linux and I am not a programmer, I am not studying for that,I do not understand how to do a lot of things, just copy-paste and expect it to work correctly, so that I used the command `dmesg` and I got this:
Actually, seeing the terminal it looks like infinite pages, so I do not know if I had to put all, so I just will copy the beggining and the errors.

```
[    0.000000] microcode: microcode updated early to revision 0xba, date = 2010-10-03
[    0.000000] Linux version 4.15.0-24-generic (buildd@lgw01-amd64-056) (gcc version 7.3.0 (Ubuntu 7.3.0-16ubuntu3)) #26-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 13 08:44:47 UTC 2018 (Ubuntu 4.15.0-24.26-generic 4.15.18)
[    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-24-generic root=UUID=63a56774-8b73-4d3b-93d7-ab3ce537a6de ro quiet splash vt.handoff=1
[    0.000000] KERNEL supported cpus:
[    0.000000]   Intel GenuineIntel
[    0.000000]   AMD AuthenticAMD
[    0.000000]   Centaur CentaurHauls
[    0.000000] x86/fpu: x87 FPU will use FXSAVE
[    0.000000] e820: BIOS-provided physical RAM map:
```

Ok... it works... I bet I put the code in the right format...

This is the first error:

```
 [drm:drm_atomic_helper_wait_for_flip_done [drm_kms_helper]] *ERROR* [CRTC:34:pipe A] flip_done timed out
```

And those are the others:

```
[   24.028148] [drm:drm_atomic_helper_wait_for_dependencies [drm_kms_helper]] *ERROR* [CRTC:34:pipe A] flip_done timed out
[   34.268150] [drm:drm_atomic_helper_wait_for_dependencies [drm_kms_helper]] *ERROR* [PLANE:28:plane A] flip_done timed out
```

Oh my God I have found more!

```
  45.737670] leds dell::kbd_backlight: Setting an LED's brightness failed (-5)
```

And more!

```
    [   54.492150] [drm:drm_atomic_helper_wait_for_flip_done [drm_kms_helper]] *ERROR* [CRTC:34:pipe A] flip_done timed out
[   64.732057] [drm:drm_atomic_helper_wait_for_dependencies [drm_kms_helper]] *ERROR* [CRTC:34:pipe A] flip_done timed out
[   74.972148] [drm:drm_atomic_helper_wait_for_dependencies [drm_kms_helper]] *ERROR* [PLANE:28:plane A] flip_done timed out
```

This are different:

```
    [   91.612285] [drm:drm_atomic_helper_wait_for_flip_done [drm_kms_helper]] *ERROR* [CRTC:41:pipe B] flip_done timed out
[  101.852261] [drm:drm_atomic_helper_wait_for_dependencies [drm_kms_helper]] *ERROR* [CRTC:41:pipe B] flip_done timed out
[  112.093150] [drm:drm_atomic_helper_wait_for_dependencies [drm_kms_helper]] *ERROR* [PLANE:35:plane B] flip_done timed out
[  123.612170] [drm:drm_atomic_helper_wait_for_flip_done [drm_kms_helper]] *ERROR* [CRTC:41:pipe B] flip_done timed out
```

I guess these ones are the same hmmm

```
[  133.852306] [drm:drm_atomic_helper_wait_for_dependencies [drm_kms_helper]] *ERROR* [CRTC:41:pipe B] flip_done timed out
[  144.092283] [drm:drm_atomic_helper_wait_for_dependencies [drm_kms_helper]] *ERROR* [PLANE:35:plane B] flip_done timed out
[  154.332157] [drm:drm_atomic_helper_wait_for_flip_done [drm_kms_helper]] *ERROR* [CRTC:41:pipe B] flip_done timed out
[  164.572307] [drm:drm_atomic_helper_wait_for_dependencies [drm_kms_helper]] *ERROR* [CRTC:41:pipe B] flip_done timed out
[  174.812305] [drm:drm_atomic_helper_wait_for_dependencies [drm_kms_helper]] *ERROR* [PLANE:35:plane B] flip_done timed out
[  189.034104] rfkill: input handler disabled
[  201.436132] [drm:drm_atomic_helper_wait_for_flip_done [drm_kms_helper]] *ERROR* [CRTC:41:pipe B] flip_done timed out
[  211.676126] [drm:drm_atomic_helper_wait_for_dependencies [drm_kms_helper]] *ERROR* [CRTC:41:pipe B] flip_done timed out
[  221.916294] [drm:drm_atomic_helper_wait_for_dependencies [drm_kms_helper]] *ERROR* [PLANE:35:plane B] flip_done timed out
[  232.156305] [drm:drm_atomic_helper_wait_for_flip_done [drm_kms_helper]] *ERROR* [CRTC:41:pipe B] flip_done timed out
[  242.396303] [drm:drm_atomic_helper_wait_for_dependencies [drm_kms_helper]] *ERROR* [CRTC:41:pipe B] flip_done timed out
[  252.636288] [drm:drm_atomic_helper_wait_for_dependencies [drm_kms_helper]] *ERROR* [PLANE:35:plane B] flip_done timed out
```

My laptop is a old Dell Latitude D630, it has:

```
4GB of RAM 3.8 says the info window
Intel® Core™2 Duo CPU T7500 @2.20GHz as processor 
Intel® 965GM for graphics
```

Well is a 2008 laptop I am not rich enough to buy a new one but it works fine but I want something faster and more beutiful than windows 10 for write docs, watch videos, for facebook, youtube etc. Actually I need W10 just for AutoCAD and Revit because I have my student license for using those programs, and for playing Ragnarok Online, I tried to play it with WINE but it ate practically all the RAM I had, so It was not an option.

I guess it takes more than 5sec open a new program and I want something faster, Could it be relationel to that errors?

I hope you can help me. 
I hope I do not receive just a spelling correction.

Thank you.

Comment: I have solved it, I just add the "video=SVIDEO-1:d" at the grub parameter, however for doing that i had to change to root since terminal, and being root i could add that, save, update and done.

Comment: you could help this community & future visitors by writing your solution in full as an answer below :)