# Could I have a faster boot time than 56 seconds?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I posted this: [Extremely slow boot, with kernel error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1052002/extremely-slow-boot-with-kernel-error)

But I've now added `video=SVIDEO-1:d` to the kernel boot parameters in `/etc/default/grub` and my boot time reduced from 4 minutes 27 seconds to 57 seconds.

I will leave the steps I here for people new to GNU/Linux as I am.

*editor's note: please see comments for minor critique of this method - use of `sudo gedit` is not recommended*

```
sudo su
```

(Enter your password)

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Now just add the `video=SVIDEO-1:d` to this line

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

It should look like this:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash video=SVIDEO-1:d"
```

Save the file and exit.

Again in the terminal, run this command to make the change effective:

```
sudo update-grub
sudo reboot
```

Now I have 57-second boot. Could it be faster?

Comment: You should always use `sudo -H gedit` instead of `sudo gedit` which can steal your regular user gedit preferences away from you. Some people here recommend NEVER using sudo with gedit.

Comment: Depends on your hardware, your HDD or ssd specifically. Also on your installation. My 16.04 system boots up in about 50 seconds, but I also have a password promt for ssd decryption in these 50 seconds. I guess an unencrypted Ubuntu should boot up in under 40 seconds on a modest system. I got an 2011 Dell Latitude E5410 with core i520 and Crucial SSD, for reference.

Comment: You could add some hardware & setup details to this to make it more answerable - you included some in your other post, but you should make this question complete without depending on a link for essential information. In particular, you could include the output of `systemd-analyze blame` to see what's taking the longest at boot.

Comment: `sudo gedit` after a `sudo su`? There is something missing, or something totally useless

Answer (score 2):

You probably got the normal boot time for a normal HDD with those 57 seconds. It was close to what I had as a boottime when I still use a hdd. systemd has a tool to examine your boot process:

```
systemd-analyze plot > /home/$USER/Pictures/plot.svg
```

This will create a picture of your boot and the time spent on each item. Maybe there is something you can disable to speed it up a bit more.

Best advice I can give though is to get an ssd. Use that as boot drive. Reinstall Ubuntu on that and mount the old hdd as a partition. Remove Ubuntu from that except for your personal data (roughly that would be anything not in /home/)

You will see the biggest improvement in boot speed for that and installation is going to quick too. Booting from a ssd takes me under 8 seconds. Installation of a new version of Ubuntu takes about 16 minutes.

---

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Please do not use sudo with graphical programs, like gedit. It might have unwanted side effects: the owner and group can change. grub is owned by root but it is better to use a command line editing tool for command line editing. Like `sudo nano /etc/default/grub` or `sudo vi /etc/default/grub`.

Comment: the owner of gedit's config file in `~` is what could change, not the owner of the file being edited. The problem is easily avoided using the `-H` flag, so that config changes are written to root's home directory